# Initializing an array in c with same numbers leads to different values

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main () {

int n[ 10 ] = {002535}; /* n is an array of 10 integers */
int j;

/* output each array element's value */
for (j = 0; j < 10; j++ ) {
  printf("Element[%d] = %d\n", j, n[j] );
}

return 0;
}
```

The above code runs and returns the first element to be equal to 1373. Could you explain this? I am not able to understand the reason behind the number being changed due to padding in the integer provided.

Output comes out to be the following lines.

```
Element[0] = 1373
Element[1] = 0
...
Element[9] = 0
```

Comment: Here, 002535 is octal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your program, you are initializing the array `n` -

```
int n[ 10 ] = {002535};
```

The number 002535 is interpreted as a **octal** number because of leading zeros.
So, this will assign the **octal** value `002535` to `n[0]` i.e. 0th location in your array `n` and rest of array elements will be initialized with `0`.

In `for` loop, you are printing it with format specifier `%d`.

The decimal equivalent of 002535 octal value is 1373. That's why you are getting `Element [0]` as 1373.

If you want to print octal number as output, use `%o` format specifier:

```
for (j = 0; j < 10; j++ ) {
  printf("Element[%d] = %o\n", j, n[j] );
```

And if you want the decimal 2535 as first element of array `n`, remove leading zeros:

```
int n[ 10 ] = {2535};
```

Answer (score 0):

An integer literal starting with `0` is interpreted as an octal number. And `02535` octal is equivalent to the decimal `1373`