# unexpected output from switch statement in c program

Tags: c

I'm getting output of `a - 0000520` when I input `a` while i should get `0001010` as per the code I've assigned. Also the default runs every time (tested using a `printf` statement) for unexplained reason. My code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int splitWord(char* word, int count);
int sunCode(char letter);

int main()
{
    char inputString[100];
    char splitStrings[10][10];
    int i, j, count;

    printf("Enter the message.\n");
    fgets(inputString, 100, stdin);
    j = count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= (strlen(inputString)); i++) {
        if (inputString[i] == ' ' || inputString[i] == '\0') {
            splitStrings[count][j] = '\0';
            count++;
            j = 0;
        }
        else {
            splitStrings[count][j] = inputString[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nOriginal String is: %s\n", inputString);
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        /*for(j=0;j<=strlen(splitStrings[i]);j++){
            printf("%s",splitStrings[i][j]);
        }*/
        splitWord(splitStrings[i], count);
    }
    return 0;
}

int splitWord(char* word, int count)
{
    int i;
    int strLength = strlen(word);
    for (i = 0; i <= strLength; i++) {
        sunCode(word[i]);
        //        printf("%c\n",word[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int sunCode(char letter)
{
    char letr = tolower(letter);
    int code = 0;
    switch (letr) {
    case '0':
        code = 0000000;
        break;
    case '1':
        code = 0000001;
        break;
    case '2':
        code = 0000010;
        break;
    case '3':
        code = 0000011;
        break;
    case '4':
        code = 0000100;
        break;
    case '5':
        code = 0000101;
        break;
    case '6':
        code = 0000110;
        break;
    case '7':
        code = 0000111;
        break;
    case '8':
        code = 0001000;
        break;
    case '9':
        code = 0001001;
        break;
    case 'a':
        code = 0001010;
        break;
    case 'b':
        code = 0001011;
        break;
    case 'c':
        code = 0001100;
        break;
    case 'd':
        code = 0001101;
        break;
    case 'e':
        code = 0001110;
        break;
    case 'f':
        code = 0001111;
        break;
    case 'g':
        code = 0010000;
        break;
    case 'h':
        code = 0010001;
        break;
    case 'i':
        code = 0010010;
        break;
    case 'j':
        code = 0010011;
        break;
    case 'k':
        code = 0010100;
        break;
    case 'l':
        code = 0010101;
        break;
    case 'm':
        code = 0010110;
        break;
    case 'n':
        code = 0010111;
        break;
    case 'o':
        code = 0011000;
        break;
    case 'p':
        code = 0011001;
        break;
    case 'q':
        code = 0011010;
        break;
    case 'r':
        code = 0011011;
        break;
    case 's':
        code = 0011100;
        break;
    case 't':
        code = 0011101;
        break;
    case 'u':
        code = 0011110;
        break;
    case 'v':
        code = 0011111;
        break;
    case 'w':
        code = -010000;
        break;
    case 'x':
        code = 010001;
        break;
    case 'y':
        code = 010010;
        break;
    case 'z':
        code = 010011;
        break;
    case ' ':
        code = 45;
        printf("\nis space\n");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    printf("%c - %07d\n", letr, code);
}
```

I tried to see if it's giving ASCII values (it isn't)
the letter is being passed properly in the `sunCode` function (it is)
I do not understand why it is behaving like this, verified the syntax and conditions of switch too.

I am using `gcc` 7.3.0 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry, Stack Overflow does not work like that. You *must* have a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: Your problem can be reduced to `int main(void) { printf("%d\n", 0001010); }`.

Comment: After your for loop in `main` you must still terminate `splitStrings[count][j]='\0'; count++;`

Comment: `char letr = tolower(letter);` may not work if letter is a digit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000395/initializing-an-array-in-c-with-same-numbers-leads-to-different-values.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I thought `tolower()` would pass everything `!isalpha()` unchanged?

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers will use different options to achieve the same results.   The posted code, when compiled, causes the compiler to output several warning/error statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Leading zeros indicate that the number is expressed in octal, or base 8; thus, 010 = 8.
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/1661378/10479742

0001010 in octal is 520 in decimal, and that's why you get that result. Either remove leading zeros, or change `code` to string.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I forgot to see the thread and figured out the solution just 10 mins ago but i didn't understand the problem, your explanation was a relief.

Comment: Feel free to mark it as an answer if it helped.

Comment: I forgot, thanks for reminding.